# How to prove two graphs are isomorphic if and only if their complements are isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory

How this can be proved that two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic iff their complements are isomorphic?

Comment: If the complements are isomorphic by some map $f:V_1\to V_2$, then $f$ is also an isomorphism between the original graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G_1 \equiv G_2 \implies \exists$ a bijective function $f: V(G_1) \rightarrow V(G_2)$ such that $xy \in E(G_1) \iff f(x)f(y) \in E(G_2)$

**Hints:**

1. Note since the vertex set of $G^c$ complement is the vertex set of $G$ itself. So $f$ can actually be considered a bijection from $V({G_1} ^ c ) \rightarrow V({G_2} ^ c )$
2. How can the statement: $xy \in E(G_1) \iff f(x)f(y) \in E(G_2)$ be expressed in terms of a negative argument, (say $xy \not \in E(G_1)$)??

Answer (score 9):

Let graph $G$ be isomorphic to $H$, and let $\overline G$, $\overline H$ denote their complements.

Since $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, then there exists a bijection $f: V(G) \to V(H)$, such that $uv \in E(G)$ if and only if $f(u)f(v) \in E(H)$. -> [this should be edge set]

Equivalently, there exists a bijection $f: V(G) \to V(H)$, such that $uv \notin E(G)$ if and only if $f(u)f(v) \notin E(H)$.  -> [this should be edge set]

Since the vertex set of $G$ and $\overline G$ are the same, therefore $f$ is a bijection from $V(\overline G)$ to $V(\overline H)$. Then suppose $uv \notin E(G)$, by definition of a complement, $uv \in E(\overline G)$. Likewise, if $f(u)f(v) \notin E(H)$, then $f(u)f(v) \in E(\overline H)$.

Hence $\overline G$ and $\overline H$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

One direction is trivial because isomorphism conquers all. The other follows from $G^{cc}=G$.