# Are all Kn graphs -1 edge isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Basically what the title says: Are all *complete* graphs with a missing edge the same graph?

> I think they are and I know my question is very simple ,yet, I only now begun getting involved in recreational maths.

Comment: There's so much symmetry, the answer has to be yes.  (For the same $n$, of course.)

Comment: They are! Try and construct a proof.

Comment: Yes, you should try.  Do it for the case $n=3$.  If you see the proof there, it extends to all $n$ very easily.

Comment: I second @William's suggestion: the answer is positive, and you should try to prove it yourself. It might be easier (psychologically, if not mathematically) to work with the complement of the graph, since two graphs are isomorphic precisely if their complements are isomorphic (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683718/how-to-prove-two-graphs-are-isomorphic-if-and-only-if-their-complements-are-isom)).

Comment: Thank you, here is a proof I tried to construct.

Comment: Let "G" have v vertices and v*(v-1)/2-1 edges. Then, "G complement" has v*(v-1)/2 - [v*(v-1)/2-1] edges (as I have previously shown). There is only one graph (ignoring labelling) having 1 edge and v vertices, so its complement G is unique. Hence, all graphs with v vertices and v(v-1)/2-1 edges are isomorphic.                                                                                      "As I noted in the post I only now started getting involved in -apart from from school maths-, viz graph theory so I cannot fully understand when a proof is correct."